# Firefox: How to remove Printed Headers & Footers

Tags: macos, firefox

I cannot seem to figure  out how to remove the Headers/Footers from *printed* Firefox pages.  Could someone please show me the way?

(I'm using Firefox 3.5.3.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the menu bar go to File → Print.

In the dialog that comes up, on the bottom you should be able to select to not print those, like I did below.

[image]

Comment: +1 for posting the appropriate OS X screenshot :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this just removes the text, it still takes up the same area of whitespace - and still ruins those terrible web pages that have custom div pagination.

Answer (score 1):

Just click File > Page Setup, then the second tab is "Margins & Header/Footer". You can change all the settings there to --blank--.

[image]

Comment: On a Mac, in the File → Page Setup you get a totally different dialog.

Comment: Didn't see the OSX tag!